# CakePHP 2 requestAction breaks my JSON encoding to Swift... invisibly

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, cakephp

I've got CakePHP 2 outputting JSON, and I've got Swift 2 code in the Xcode iPhone emulator loading that JSON data.

In my Controller, here's the code that generates the JSON:

```
public function iosDemoIndex() {
    $studentDataIn = $this->Student->getStudentsByUserId(298, 'rASC');
    $studentDataOut = [];
    foreach ($studentDataIn as $student) {
        //$currentIep = $this->Iep->requestAction('/ieps/getCurrentIep/' . $student['Student']['id']);
        $goals = $this->Goal->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Goal.student_id =' => $student['Student']['id'])));
        $goalHolder = array();
        foreach ($goals as $goal) {
            array_push($goalHolder, $goal['Goal']['goal_title']);
        }
        array_push($studentDataOut, array('studentName' => $student['Student']['l_name']. ", " . $student['Student']['f_name'], 'studentGoals' => $goalHolder));
    }
    $this->set(array(
    'students' => $studentDataOut,
    '_serialize' => array('students')
    ));
}
```

Which works fine.  My Swift code succesfully loads the students array via the JSON into an array of structs.  But if I simply un-comment line 5 (which grabs data that I ultimately hope to use to restrict the find in line 6), Xcode gives me:

```
Error with Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}
```

Line 5 shouldn't alter the JSON document in any way.  And when I look at the JSON itself, it looks the same regardless of whether the line's commented out.

So, any ideas what an unrelated, ought-to-be invisible requestAction could be doing that's breaking my JSON... in a way that I can't see when I look at it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity (future-me):

It was a login issue.  The reason the JSON looked identical in my browser was that I had an active user session in the browser at the time.  Without that session, (for instance when the iOS emulator tried to load the JSON page) the CakePHP was returning a redirect to login.  Viable solutions include replicating the requestAction code in the JSON-generating controller (though that's not very DRY), or establishing proper login handling on the Swift side of things.